# Using URL to display all system options for phone number in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

Swift has a class called `UITextView`, which has a property called `dataDetectorTypes` which would automatically scan the text for specified data types, (like phone numbers, maps locations etc.) highlight found occurrences, and provide options on user interaction. I am currently transitioning my app to use SwiftUI, and am struggling to reimplement a specific behavior of the data detector. *Namely, when a phone number is tapped, it offers the option to call, but when force touched (or I assume long pressed) it offers multiple options from across the system, ranging from first party messaging apps to third party ones.* The following two images show what I am referring to:

Call option on tap
[image: Call option on tap]

System wide options on force touch
[image: System wide options on force touch]

I have tried wrapping the `UITextView` inside a `UIViewRepresentable`, and this works for the most part, but it is ugly and makes integration with the rest of the app a bit more tricky. And after all, the way I am using it, there isn't really a need for all the power of a `UITextView`. It really is just a button with a link.

I am not sure what SwiftUI element to use, but have given the following considerations:

- `Text`: though I don't think this can handle user interaction
- `Link`: this might be relevant, but would mean I would need to set the minimum requirement to iOS 14
- `Button`: this option seems the most promising. Using other SO answers, I have something like this:

```
Button("Click Me") {
    guard let url = URL(string: "telprompt://\(self.phoneString)"),
    UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return }
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}.foregroundColor(.blue)
```

However this only achieves the first behavior, an option to call on tap, and not the second behavior. Is there a way to compose a phone URL in Swift to open multiple system generated options? Or should I be doing something different, using a different Xcode function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to access that system action sheet programmatically. You could probably try to replicate all the buttons one-by-one, but honestly I would just use a `UITextView` wrapped in a `UIViewRepresentable`.

What problems are you having with that? I was having some layout issues, that were solved by using a SwiftUI `Text` view as a template.

Below is the class I was using. It detects all types of data, but you could easily modify it to just detect phone numbers.

```
struct DataDetectorText: View {
    let text: String

    init(_ text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text(text + "\n")
            .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            .hidden()
            .overlay(DataDetectorTextView(text: text))
    }
}

private struct DataDetectorTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let text: String

    func makeUIView(context _: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()

        view.text = text
        view.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .body)

        view.dataDetectorTypes = [.all]
        view.isEditable = false
        view.isSelectable = true

        view.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        view.isScrollEnabled = false
        view.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context _: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        uiView.sizeToFit()
    }
}
```